# New line after a raw_input

Tags: python

First off I'm so new at programming and python in general so sorry in advance.

I'm trying to get input from a user using raw input, but also working on making my code simpler.

What I had originally was:

```
print "Please give the name of your project."
project_name = raw_input()
```

Which gave me:
"Please give the name of your project."
Test

To shorten it I moved to:

```
project_name = raw_input("Please give the name of your project.")
```

Which gives me:
"Please give the name of your project."test

So it's asking for the user to enter info right after the prompt. I would like it on a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a newline to your prompt:

```
project_name = raw_input("Please give the name of your project.\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put in a newline:

```
>>> project_name = raw_input("Please give the name of your project.\n")
Please give the name of your project.
myProject
>>> project_name
'myProject'
>>>
```

In the prompt string, `\n` creates a newline.